# I don't know where to add {{ $user->getReferralLink() }}

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a github author's reference system project to my project. I did everything but stuck on the last step. He gave me the code to get the reference link, but I don't know where or in which file to add it.

Here GitHub link: https://github.com/questocat/laravel-referral

step where i got stuck and don't know where to add;

```php
$user = App\User::findOrFail(1);

{{ $user->getReferralLink() }}
```

I tried doing

```html
<p>{{ $user->getReferralLink() }} </p>
```

on a sample page, but it didn't work. I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Do you have any controllers and views?  How do you pass data from a controller to a view in the rest of your project?  This is no different.

Comment: is a normal laravel project. if this answer is false i'm so sory. i'm türkish because translating on google. sorry sir

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: sir, my question is; In which file should I add the code? I don't have much php knowledge. I would appreciate it if you could be more clear. I couldn't understand much from the link you sent :(

Comment: Can you add a sample code of what you did

Comment: @xenooooo <p>{{ $user->getReferralLink() }} </p> prints the code as it is. I added php tags and @ sign but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using it in a .blade.php file ?

Comment: @xenooooo yes. profile.blade.php